# Conditional Gaussian from Joint Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, joint-distribution

I have the random variables $X$ and $Y$ related through the following:
\begin{align}
X &= N_X \\
Y &= 4X + N_Y 
\end{align}
where $N_X, N_Y \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal N(0,1)$. Is there a faster way to derive the conditional density $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ than computing the joint distribution and dividing it by the marginal distribution of $Y$? For reference, for $y=2$, we should obtain $f_{X|Y=2}(x) = \mathcal 
 N(8/17, 1/17)$.

Comment: This is classical linear regression, so if you are familiar with the theory and formulas you can immediately write down the answer--but if not, then developing that theory would not be any faster!

Comment: which expression of linear regression do you have in mind?

Comment: Ordinary least squares.